# Vue-cli import css not work

Tags: css, webpack, vue.js, import, vue-cli

```
<style src="@/assets/css/base.css"> ->ok
<style src="./assets/css/base.css"> ->error

This dependency was not found:
* !!vue-style-loader!css-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler/index?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-656039f0","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./assets/css/base.css in ./src/components/HelloWorld.vue

To install it, you can run: npm install --save !!vue-style-loader!css-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler/index?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-656039f0","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./assets/css/base.css

@import '@/assets/css/base.css' ->error
@import './assets/css/base.css' ->error

Module build failed: Error: Failed to find '@/assets/css/base.css'
@ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader!./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-656039f0","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/components/HelloWorld.vue 4:14-312 13:3-17:5 14:22-320
```

I search a lot of methods, and I tried, but it doesn't work.
I do't know which method can solute my problem.

Comment: To clarify, you're specifically looking for a way to use the `@import` keyword inside the `style` tag? Why not just use the `<style src="...">` method, which you confirmed works?

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder called static, put your css in and include link in your index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/fille.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option seems to be, inside the `App.vue` file, within the `<script>` tag:

```
<script>
import "@/assets/css/base.css";
export default {};
</script>
```

But

```
<style src="@/assets/css/base.css"></style>
```

works just as well.